# Display a node counter, by specific content type?

Tags: 6, nodes

How can I display a counter e.g. Total News: 999, Total Blog posts: 123, etc. ?
(looking for d6 solution actually)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Count Nodes](http://drupal.org/project/count) module.

> The Count Nodes Module counts total number of nodes created(published
>   and unpublished both) in each content type. It provide a total number
>   of blocks equals to the total number of content types created such
>   that administrator can use one block for each content type.

Comment: no Drupal 7 version yet, any solution available for D7 ?